# Assignment error cast in C

Tags: c, casting, variable-assignment

I have the following code:

```
struct message_t *msg = ( struct message_t* ) malloc ( sizeof( struct message_t ) );
struct server_t *server = ( struct server_t* ) malloc ( sizeof( struct server_t ) );

server = network_connect( argv[ 2 ] );
```

The function network_connect return a struct server_t. However I contentiously get the error:

> warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default].

I don't understand this error... first I didn't allocated memory to my pointer server_t. Well I get the error and try allocate memory and nothing. I review the code network_connect and all is right.

Comment: What is the prototype for `network_connect()` - I'm suspecting the return type is not `struct server_t *`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My psychic powers tell me that you're missing the function prototype (declaration) for the `network_connect` function—make sure to include the header file that it's contained in.

In C, the compiler allows *implicit declarations*: when the compiler sees a new function name it's never seen before (such as `network_connect`), it assumes that it takes an arbitrary number and types of arguments and that it returns `int`.  So, due to the implicit function declaration, the compiler thinks you're trying to convert from an `int` to a `struct server_t*`, which results in the given warning.

You also have a memory leak in your code—you're allocating memory for the `server` object with `malloc`, and then you immediately overwrite that pointer with the value returned by `network_connect`, so that memory you allocated is gone forever.  There's no need to allocate any memory in this case, since `network_connect` directly returns its value.

Finally, in C, there's no need to cast the return value of `malloc`.  `malloc` returns a `void*`, and C (but not C++) allows an implicit cast from `void*` to any other pointer type.  A cast here is just unnecessary extra verbosity, and it can actually hide errors—if you forget to include `<stdlib.h>`, then any use of `malloc` will use an implicit declaration (see above) that returns `int`.  A cast will hide the error (that you forgot to include `<stdlib.h>`), whereas having no cast will give you a warning.

Comment: I'm so dumb!!
Yeah, I forgot #include header network_client.h in network_client_private.h. Thank you very much!

Comment: I read in many article the same, but my teacher always ask for cast all malloc. =X
So we cast!
I'll remove the malloc, like you said. In the beginning I wasn't allocating memory, but I was getting errors, so I try allocate. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Going by your description of the `network_connect` declaration, and the error message, I would say that `network_connect` looks something like

```
struct server_t network_connec(char *);
```

The above declaration says that the function returns the structure *as is*, i.e. it returns a copy. But you declare the variable `server` to be a *pointer*, and you can't assign a non-pointer value to a pointer. The solution is to not make the `server` variable a pointer (because that allocation will introduce a memory leak) and just declare it as a normal non-pointer variable:

```
struct server_t server;
```

Comment: The network_connect is declared like
struct server_t *network_connect(char * );
I introduce the include and solve the problem. Thanks.